# ItextSharp - Set pdf paper size to 8.5x13

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm trying to set the paper size of my generated pdf in VB.NET

```
Dim myWidth As String
Dim myHeight As String
myWidth = "8.5"
myHeight = "1300"
Dim pgSize As New iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(myWidth, myHeight)
Dim doc As New iTextSharp.text.Document(pgSize.Rotate, 0.0F, 0.0F, 0.0F, 100.0F)
```

But the problem is the paper size is not setting to 8.5x13

The generated PDF paper size is Width=8.26 and Height=11.69"

How can I change the paper size to 8.5X13 and rotate it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its okay guys i found a reference here
http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/how-to-change-pdf-document-page-size-in-Asp-Net-with-C-Sharp-usng-itextsharp-1024.aspx

and this is what i do

```
 PdfDoc = New Document(New Rectangle(579.5F, 936.0F).Rotate)
```